# Intermittent SSL handshake failures between Rails and Play Framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, playframework-2.0, httparty

We have two services, the client is a Rails app, the server is a REST API built using the Play Framework.  We use the HTTParty client in Rails.

We get intermittent SSL handshake errors between these two services.  On Play, we get the following error:

```
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev graph:  org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler - SSLEngine.closeInbound() raised an exception after a handshake failure.
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev javax.net.ssl.SSLException:  Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1619)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1587)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.closeInbound(SSLEngineImpl.java:1517)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1407)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1293)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:913)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
Jan 09 14:37:47 graph-dev at:  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

On Rails, the corresponding error:

```
Error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A: sslv3 alert handshake failure
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `block in connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in `request'
```

Our SSL certificate is issued by RapidSSL.  On Play, we include a cross-root certificate signed by Equifax validating GeoTrust.

We've been trying to figure this out for a few days now and we're really at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

An answer was provided on the Play mailing list.  We added `DiffieHellman` to the end of the default value for  `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` and that solved it.

Credit goes to Will Sargent on that list.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/ECee_w2wlrU